# how to monitor JVM heap memory in GKE cluster PODS using stackdriver

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have to monitor Java container in GKE using stackdriver. Since stackdriver agent can't be installed in GKE nodes[COS image]. What is the way to monitor JVM??

Comment: My gut would have said to install the JVM agent described here ... https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm   what makes you think that you can't install an agent in a container?

Comment: the agent is already running on each node.  I guess it might be possible to run two agents?  The GKE managed one and your own?

Answer (score 0):

At first, have a look at the Stackdriver Logging agent [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/):

> Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) includes managed support for
>   Stackdriver Monitoring and Stackdriver Logging.

more details you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing).

In addition to [JVM Monitoring plugin](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm) that mentioned *@Kolban*, you can try to achieve your goal with [JMX extporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) and/or [Kube eagle](https://github.com/cloudworkz/kube-eagle) exporters to [Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/monitoring-apps-running-on-multiple-gke-clusters-using-prometheus-and-stackdriver) and [Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7727).

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/monitoring-apps-running-on-multiple-gke-clusters-using-prometheus-and-stackdriver This should help..I will check and update... I think JVM plugin can't be configured in GKE nodes as it requires monitoring agent